# how does onchange function works for date

Tags: javascript, onchange

So I'm trying some adding date, I thinking that I set my validity to 10 days it add to the current date and if I change the current date to change date, it plus to change date

```
    var $ctrl_newdate = moment($ctrl_DateRequested.val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')));
    var $ctrl_plusdate = $ctrl_newdate.add(10,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    $ctrl_DateRequested.val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    $ctrl_ValidityDate.val($ctrl_plusdate);
    $ctrl_ReturnDate.val($ctrl_plusdate);
    
    $ctrl_DateRequested.change(function (){
      var $ctrl_newdate = moment($ctrl_DateRequested.val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')));
      var $ctrl_plusdate = $ctrl_newdate.add(10,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      $ctrl_DateRequested.val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      $ctrl_ValidityDate.val($ctrl_plusdate);
      $ctrl_ReturnDate.val($ctrl_plusdate);
    });
```

The adding the date is working but the change is not

Comment: [I doubt what you are saying is real.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Prove it !](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank you for the answers, I already fixed the code

here's the code

```
var $ctrl_DateRequested = $('[name = ctrl_Textbox_lgog5]');
var $ctrl_ValidityDate = $('[name = ctrl_Textbox_wag79]');
var $ctrl_ReturnDate = $('[name = ctrl_Textbox_cg71z]');
var $ctrl_newdate = moment($ctrl_DateRequested.val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')));
$ctrl_DateRequested.on('change',function(){
    var date = $(event.target).val();
   
 $ctrl_ValidityDate.val(moment(date).add(10,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')) ;  
 $ctrl_ReturnDate.val(moment(date).add(10,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')) ; 
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `change` is a valid function. Try using

```
processDates();

$ctrl_DateRequested.addEventListener('change', e => {
  processDates();
});
```

Also avoid duplicating code. You can create a function to do this task.

Comment: there seems to be jquery involved. with or without the op‘s knowledge

Comment: Yeah and also, if a datepicker is being used on the input, maybe that's not sending `change` event, can't say. You could also try `input` event but then you'll have to handle the case of incomplete dates as the user types.